# onRequestPermissionsResult never gets called in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

Below code is working fine in Activity but I **cannot make it work inside a Fragment.**

The `onRequestPermissionsResult` is never gets called.

There is a `requestPermissions` function in API level 23 (Android 6.0) but I need to make it work on lower levels like API level 21 (Android 5.0) so unfortunetely I cannot use that. `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` just simply not calls `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

Any suggestion?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

final int REQUEST_CODE = 120;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater infl, ViewGroup cont, Bundle bundle) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("LOG", "Asking for permission right now..");

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_CODE);


        //This is working but needs API level 23 (Android 6.0) - How to make this work on Android 5.0?
        //requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    return super.onCreateView(infl, cont, bundle);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    Log.i("LOG", "onRequestPermissionsResult!");

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("LOG", "GRANTED");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GRANTED,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Log.i("LOG", "REFUSED");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "REFUSED,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `onCreateView` is a terrible choice for calling `requestPermissions` move it into `onResume`

Comment: @Selvin I do not call it in production code. It is just a small dummy code that can show and reproduce easily the error.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understant well your idea, if your android device is on 5.0, so why you need to request the permission??

Comment: @PhạmLam It is 5.0+

Comment: also you should call Fragment's method not static ActivityCompat's method (which is written in similar question here on SO - **which means that you didn't even tried to do some internet search on this topic** )

Comment: Replace `ActivityCompat` with `FragmentCompat` and call its `requestPermissions()` method. As it stands, `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is being called... on the activity that you are passing to `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`.

Answer (score 0):

Call fragment.onRequestPermissionResult inside the onRequestPermissionResult of the hosting activity.

Comment: I work in a fragment, thats the whole point

Answer (score 0):

Requesting permissions in runtime was added in API 23. So it will not work in older versions. In API older than 23 permissions were granted at install time.

Edit: before asking for permission just call checkSelfPermission and call your code if already granted instead of asking for permission.